# Gradle JAR files in a folder recursively

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

How can I JAR a folder and all of it's sub directories and files in a simple JAR?
I tried something like this and it does not work.

```
task jarVrCore(type: Jar, description: 'JARs core part of the project') {
    doLast {
        archiveName = "vasasdasasdasd"
        from "${projectDir}"
        println "${vrCoreSourceDir}"
        destinationDir = file("${dirTmpLibsVr4}")
    }
}
```

I always get an empty JAR with only the manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that all of your task configurations are applied **too late**. You are using a `doLast` closure, which is executed **after** the actual task action (for a `Jar` task: the creation of the `.jar` file).

Normally, all task configuration is done directly inside the task configuration closure:

```
task jarVrCore(type: Jar, description: 'JARs core part of the project') {
    archiveName = "vasasdasasdasd"
    from "${projectDir}"
    println "${vrCoreSourceDir}"
    destinationDir = file("${dirTmpLibsVr4}")
}
```

If you need to apply configuration after other tasks have been executed, use a `doFirst` closure.

Please note, that using the example above, the `println` statement will be executed during *configuration phase* and therefore on each Gradle invocation, whether the task `jarVrCore` is executed or not.